# Selecting Dates from Monday to Saturday and Hours Between Morning 8:00:00 AM To Next Day Morning 7:00:00 AM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to work on a query where there is date selection in the where clause i.e. if sysdate is Monday I have to get the dates from Monday to Saturday and Hours Between Morning 08:00:00 AM to Next Day Morning 07:00:00 AM. I am hardcoding the dates and Hours in the where clause, When I run the query data does not show.

**Query:**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS'), REPLACE(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY'), ' ')
  FROM dual
 WHERE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '08:01:00' AND '08:00:00'
   AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY') >= 'MONDAY'
   AND TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DAY') <= 'SATURDAY';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the wider range first (from 8 AM at Monday till the end of a Saturday, if I understood correctly) and then exclude time from 7 AM till 8 AM.

In the below code `iw` format element stands for ISO week, that starts on the Monday.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     date '2022-04-17'
>       + interval '01:30:00' hour to second
>       + interval '2' hour * level
>     as dt
>   from dual
>   connect by level < 90
> )
> select
>   to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') as day_
>   , listagg(to_char(dt, 'hh24:mi'), ',')
>   within group (order by dt asc) as hours
> from a
> where 1 = 1
>   /*From Mon 08 AM*/
>   and dt > trunc(dt, 'iw') +
>     interval '8' hour
>   /*Till Sat end of the day*/
>   and dt < trunc(dt, 'iw') + 6
>   /*and except minutes between 7 and 8 AM*/
>   and not (
>     to_char(dt, 'hh24mi') < '0800'
>     and to_char(dt, 'hh24mi') > '0700'
>   )
> group by to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd')
> ```
>
> ```
> DAY_     | HOURS                                                            
> :------- | :----------------------------------------------------------------
> 20220418 | 09:30,11:30,13:30,15:30,17:30,19:30,21:30,23:30                  
> 20220419 | 01:30,03:30,05:30,09:30,11:30,13:30,15:30,17:30,19:30,21:30,23:30
> 20220420 | 01:30,03:30,05:30,09:30,11:30,13:30,15:30,17:30,19:30,21:30,23:30
> 20220421 | 01:30,03:30,05:30,09:30,11:30,13:30,15:30,17:30,19:30,21:30,23:30
> 20220422 | 01:30,03:30,05:30,09:30,11:30,13:30,15:30,17:30,19:30,21:30,23:30
> 20220423 | 01:30,03:30,05:30,09:30,11:30,13:30,15:30,17:30,19:30,21:30,23:30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=70f41c299a770bfbed5142674fd8c0f1)*

Answer (score 0):

(And what if sysdate isn't Monday?)

Therefore, could you explain a little bit better what is the *input* (dates? One date? SYSDATE?) and what is desired *output* (related to that *input*).

Basically, I don't understand what you want. Meanwhile, errors you made (if it'll help).

---

**Format model** is wrong; this is what you did:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') day, length(to_char(sysdate, 'DAY')) len from dual;

DAY              LEN
--------- ----------
FRIDAY             9
```

"FRIDAY" doesn't have 9 characters; it has 6 of them --> use the `fm` format modifier (it'll truncate trailing spaces):

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'fmDAY') day, length(to_char(sysdate, 'fmDAY')) len from dual;

DAY              LEN
--------- ----------
FRIDAY             6

SQL>
```

---

Today (22.04.2022) is Friday. Your query searches for data whose day is between "MONDAY" and "SATURDAY". As you're comparing **strings** and alphabet goes as [A, B, ..., **F**, G, ..., **M**, N, ..., **S**, T], "F(riday)" is NEVER between M(onday) and S(aturday) so there's zero chance that it'll work.

---

As of **hours**: which time exactly is between 08:01 and 08:00? Time doesn't go *backwards* (unless you meant "08:01 today and 08:00 tomorrow").

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a combination

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt,'HH24:MI:SS','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS Hour, 
       TO_CHAR(dt,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS day
  FROM t
 WHERE TO_CHAR(dt,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') IN ('Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri')
   AND TO_CHAR(dt, 'HH24:MI:SS') NOT BETWEEN '07:00:01' AND '08:00:00'
    OR TO_CHAR(dt,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') = 'Mon'
   AND TO_CHAR(dt, 'HH24:MI:SS')>= '07:00:00'
    OR TO_CHAR(dt,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') = 'Sat'
   AND TO_CHAR(dt, 'HH24:MI:SS')<= '08:00:00'
```

where needs to consider restricting the periods for the bound dates individually

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cc310e1a1e659a6f8dd7562d0aa5af59)</kbd>

Comment: `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` does not affect the output of `TO_CHAR(dt, 'd')`. It is affected by the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting and that is not a valid parameter for the 3rd argument of `TO_CHAR` so this will not give consistent results if you are in `BANGLADESH` (weeks start on Friday), `EGYPT` (weeks start on Saturday), `AMERICA` (weeks start on Sunday) or `GERMANY` (weeks start on Monday). [db<.fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b95538acdef6c0a3e16e6b0346cc34b2)

Answer (score 0):

> if sysdate is Monday I have to get the dates from Monday to Saturday and Hours Between Morning 08:00:00 AM to Next Day Morning 07:00:00 AM.

You can find whether `SYSDATE` is Monday by comparing the day to the start of the ISO week (which will always be midnight on Monday):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') < 1
```

You can find out whether the hours are between 08:00 and 07:00 the next day by subtracting 8 hours and finding out whether the time is between 00:00 and 23:00:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '8' HOUR) - TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '8' HOUR)) DAY TO SECOND
         <= INTERVAL '23' HOUR;
```

You can combine the two to find out if the day is between Monday and Saturday and the time is between 08:00 and 07:00 on the next day (so for Saturday, it would include 7 hours of Sunday) using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '8' HOUR) - TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '8' HOUR), 'IW') < 6
AND    (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '8' HOUR) - TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '8' HOUR)) DAY TO SECOND
         <= INTERVAL '23' HOUR;
```

*Note: This does not use `TO_CHAR` so it is unaffected by any changes to the `NLS_TERRITORY` or `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` session parameters so it will always give the same answer (independent of the settings of the user who runs the query).*